# Flutter - How can I build chat app that implement read or not read message feature?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I try to make a chat application that has read or not read messages feature. But I truly have no idea how to implement it.

[image]

I currently use firestore as the database to store the message.

I use streambuilder to stream the message and rebuild UI every time message is added to the chat room.

Can I have a suggestion on what widget I should be looking for or any ideas on how I can implement it?

Comment: Let's say you have (Alice and Bob). Alice sends a message (firestore document) when Bob reads the message (firestore document) it update a value. That value could be a **bool isRead**.

Comment: thanks for the reply. when Alice sends a message **(isRead is false)** and when Bob read (what you mean by read is when the chat UI is rebuild right?) **isRead become True**. What will happen if Bob application is in the background? Do the streambuilder  rebuild chat UI? if not that might actually work.

Comment: By changing  **isRead** I'm mean when Bob enter the chats the messages will load then he'll grab the last document and change **isRead = true**. and he will do so every time he enters the chat or a new message is received. **Do streambuilder rebuild chat UI in background?** I couldn't find any good documentation about it, But i think the UI updates only if the app is in the foreground !! You can post another question about this topic.

Comment: anyway, thanks for the idea I will try implementing it. 

Comment: Hi,
after almost a year, did you come to a solution?

I'm looking for something similar and I'd be glad to have a starting point.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering what would trigger flutter to update isRead to true? If we were to trigger the function only when the user push to the screen then if the user is already on the screen when a new message is sent, wouldn't this mean that the function to update isRead to true will not be triggered?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is create a Firestore collection for the conversation of users. To send a message, store the messages as a document of the conversation collection along with the timestamp and an `isRead` boolean flag. Also add a `sender` value since this is where we'll know if the message came from the user or not.

```
Collection 
-- conversation_userA_userB
   -- Document
      -- message: "Hello"
         sender: userA
         timestamp: {UNIX_TIME}
         isRead: true
      -- message: "Hi"
         sender: userB
         timestamp: {UNIX_TIME}
         isRead: false
```

Once the user has seen the message, update the isRead flag of the message if it came from the other user. The app can listen to the collection using a Stream so the UI can be updated in real-time.